# select quotes but NOT apostrophes in REGEX

Tags: ruby, regex, quotes, apostrophe

I would like to achieve this amazing result (I'm using Ruby):

```
input:  "Joe can't tell between 'large' and large."   
output: "Joe can't tell between large and large."
```

getting rid of the quotes but not of the apostrophe
how can I do it in a simple way?

my failed overcomplicated attempt:

```
 entry = test[0].gsub(/[[']*1]/, "")
```

Comment: And what about "Students' uniform"?

Comment: I would have posted [`.gsub(/\B'\b|\b'\B/, '')`](http://ideone.com/C0jZn1) but for the above comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest one for your situation could be something like this.

**Regex:** `/\s'|'\s/` and replace with a `space`.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sK8cA0/1)**

---

You can also go with `/(['"])([A-Za-z]+)\1/` and replace with `\2` i.e second captured group.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sK8cA0/2)**

Comment: Might also work with `\b` to be safe, capturing things like `'test',thing`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a script to demo an answer:

```
x = "Joe can't tell between 'large' and large."
puts x.gsub(/'\s|\s'/, " ")
# Output: Joe can't tell between large and large.
```

To decode what this script does - the gsub / regex line is saying:

> Find all (an apostrophe followed by a space **'/s**) or (a space
>   followed by an apostrophe **\s'**) and replace it with space.

This leaves apostrophes that aren't adjacent to spaces intact, which seems to remove only the apostrophes the OP is trying to remove.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this one?

```
entry = test[0].gsub(/[^']/, "")
```

But it should remove **all** `'`.

Answer (score 0):

This does exactly what you are looking for, including ignoring the posted comments `Students'` example.

`entry = test[0].gsub(/'(­[^\s]+)'/,­ '\1')`

I don't have ruby set up, but i confirmed this works here: http://tryruby.org/levels/1/challenges/0

Here is an example on regex101:

https://regex101.com/r/aY8aJ3/1